# How do I get AutoFixture AutoMoq to return results from injected services in an instantiated object?

Tags: c#, moq, autofixture

I am trying to test a service class that consumers a repository service. I have customizations set up that I believe should work with my repository service, but instead return default Anonymous results. If you look at the code sample below, I'm trying to get the "Foo" objects that I registered in the Customization Class back when I call the svc.GetFoos method, instead I get nothing:

```
void Main()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(
        new CompositeCustomization(
            new Customization(),
            new AutoMoqCustomization())); 

    var svc = fixture.CreateAnonymous<Bar>(); 

    Console.Write(svc.GetFoos().Count()); 
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Bar
{

    public IQueryable<Foo> GetFoos()
    {
        return _rep.Query<Foo>(); 
    }

    public Bar(IRepository rep) { _rep = rep;  }

    private IRepository _rep; 
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Name {get;set;}   
}

public class Customization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        var f = fixture
                .Build<Foo>()
                .With(x => x.Name, "FromCustomize")
                .CreateMany(2)
                .AsQueryable();
        fixture.Register<IQueryable<Foo>>(() => f); 
    }
}

public interface IRepository
{
    IQueryable<T> Query<T>(); 
}
```

If I add the following code to the Main method after the fixture instantiation, it works how I want, but then I'm manually setting up my mocks, and I'm not sure what AutoFixture AutoMoq is getting me:

```
var mock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<IRepository>>(); 
mock
    .Setup(x => x.Query<Foo>())
    .Returns(fixture.CreateAnonymous<IQueryable<Foo>>);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AutoFixture.AutoMoq works as an [Auto-Mocking Container](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/03/11/auto-mocking-container/). It'll automatically compose object graphs by injecting `Mock<T>` instances into any consumer of said `T`.

It can't configure the `Mock<T>` instances for you - after all, how could it? Only you (the test writer) knows what the appropriate interaction should be.

So the code you present, including the calls to `Setup` and `Returns`, is correct, although you may consider whether or not the `Customization` class is overkill.

If you need to automate a lot of repetitious setup of Moq, you should consider

- whether the interface design and the consumption pattern is appropriate
- if a [Fake](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163358.aspx) wouldn't be a better option than a dynamic mock

Comment: I assumed it would determine what to return based on what I setup in the Customization, as in, the Mock knows I'm calling a method with a return of IQueryable<Foo>, so it'll use the values I registered for that.
As for the Customization, this is a very simplified version of what my actual test class looks like.

Comment: Is this still the case? Autofixture seems to be able to handle generics just fine. fixture.Create<Task<MyContainer<List<string>>>() is able to properly generate all the expected objects all the way down to the string level.

But if I have an interface than mockedService.Object.Get<string>() returns a null and can't seem to figure out that Get<string>(), which has a signature of T Get<T>() should return a string.

I'm having a hard time understanding why it should work in the first instance but not when using AutoMoq.

Comment: @Riplikash The [answer you got here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33249125/126014) seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across a similar topic. I was unable to execute queries for my automatically created `IQueryable<T>`.

> Expression of type 'System.Object' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.String]' of method 'Boolean Any...

I worked around this by creating a special specimen builder which always creates an array instead, and returns it `AsQueryable`.
In the end I did not use the code, but it works.

Very rough obviously, just trying things out...

```cs
void Main()
{
    Fixture fixture = new Fixture();

    fixture.Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization { ConfigureMembers = true, Relay = new QueryableBuilder() });

    // Possible ways to "override" the AutoMoqBehavior
//  fixture.Inject<string>("hallO");
//  fixture.Inject(new[] { "asd" });
//  fixture.Inject(new[] { "asds" }.AsQueryable());

    var queryable = fixture.Create<Foo>();
    queryable.Bar();

    fixture.Create<IQueryable<string>>().Any(x => x.Equals("asd"));
}

public class QueryableBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    MockRelay _Base = new MockRelay();

    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var t = request as Type;
        if (t == null ||
            !t.IsGenericType ||
            t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(IQueryable<>))
            return _Base.Create(request, context);

        var queryableTypeName = typeof(IQueryable<>).Name;
        if (t.Name != queryableTypeName)
            return _Base.Create(request, context);

        var entityType = t.GetGenericArguments().Single();

        var tt = entityType.MakeArrayType();
        dynamic blbb = context.Resolve(tt);
        return ((IEnumerable)blbb).AsQueryable();
    }
}

public interface IHaveQueryable {
    IQueryable<string> Queryable {get;}
}

public class Foo {

    readonly IHaveQueryable _Queryable;

    public Foo(IHaveQueryable queryable){
        _Queryable = queryable;
    }

    public bool Bar(){
        return _Queryable.Queryable.Any(x => x.Equals("bar"));
    }
}
```