# Using AutoMoq methods with generic signatures

Tags: autofixture, automoq

I'm currently using a test framework I've thrown together using xUnit, AutoMoq, AutoFixture, and AutoFixture.XUnit2. I'm running into issues with mocking methods with generic signatures.

AutoFixture seems to handle generic items just fine. If I ask for a `CustomeObject<Task<List<Task<string>>>>`, or some other ridiculous nested generic type, it seems to generate them as expected all the way down to the last node.

However, if I have an interface like this:

```
public interface ITestInterface{
    T Get<T>();
}
```

and then try to call the method from the mock I got from AutoMoq it just returns null. So, for example:

```
[Theory]
[MyAutoDaqaAttribute]
public async Task ATest(
    Mock<ITestInterface> service
) {
    var result = service.Object.Get<string>();
}
```

In this code result will be null. That seems odd to me. Shouldn't it go to autofixture and try to create a value of type T i.e. a new string? It seems like Autofixture has already shown that it can handle generics just fine.

Or do you always just have to manually setup any mock method that has a generic in its signature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mocked objects don't go through AutoFixture by default. You can use the `AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization` for that though.

However, in your case, the method is generic.
`AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization` doesn't work with generic methods, you'll have to manually set up the method.

Extracted from [here](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/wiki/Cheat-Sheet#auto-configured-mocks):

> `AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization` does not configure generic methods either. You can, however, easily set these up using the `ReturnsUsingFixture` extension method:
>
> ```
> converter.Setup(x => x.Convert<double>("10.0"))
>          .ReturnsUsingFixture(fixture);
> ```

Comment: Right, I should have noted I way using AutoConfiguredMoqCustomizations. But thanks for confirming that AutoConfiguredMoqCustomizations can't configure generic methods.

So it looks like I can't avoid doing some level of setup, but I could at least avoid having to set up the return values by using ReturnsUsingFixture. I'll try that out. Thanks.