# AutoMock setup with AutoFixture Data Theories

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, autofixture, automoq

Ok, as was answered in my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33248438/using-automoq-methods-with-generic-signatures/33249125), `AutoMoq` does not use AutoFixture by default. That's fine and easily solved by doing a setup and setting `ReturnsUsingFixture`.

But can that be setup with Auto Fixture Data Theories?

So we have a custom AutoDataAttribute that I'll call `[MyAutoData]`. And in there we call and set up a bunch of customizations like `AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization`, configuring it to produce webapi controllers, and registering a lot of custom generators. So we've been able to pull out ALMOST all of the boilerplate configuration into some basic configuration files. We've even set up the `MyAutoData` attribute for system tests, so if you ask for, say, an `Id<Account>` it will go and create a new account using the actual webapi calls and return a valid account id.

But how can you handle that for setting up `AutoMoq` method returns? Here is an example:

```
    [Theory, MyAutoData]
    public async Task Test(Mock<ICqrsService> mockService, TheRequest request) 
    {
        mockService.Setup(service => service.CreateAsync<TheRequest>(It.IsAny<TheRequest>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(result); // or similar car with ReturnUsingFixture
        /* now we can test */
    }
```

In every other case, we've been able to move this kind of configuration into `MyAutoData` (or into a class it calls). But for AutoMoq I can't see how it should work. We can't do a fixture.

Is there a way to trigger a setup method after AutoFixture generates an item but before it is delivered to the test method? Or is there a way to customize the AutoMoq behavior to just ALWAYS use `.ReturnsUsingFixture(fixture)`? Or am I just thinking about this problem all wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`IPostprocessComposer<T>.Do(Action<T>)`](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture/Dsl/IPostprocessComposer.cs#L13-L22) method allows you to further customize a specimen *after* it has been created.

In your case, you could use it inside a customization to setup a *generic method* on a Test Double to return an object created by AutoFixture:

```
public class FakeServiceCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customize<Mock<IService>>(composer =>
            composer.Do(fake =>
                fake.Setup(service => service.Create<Something>())
                    .ReturnsUsingFixture(fixture);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, I already think that `AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization` is too implicit for my tastes. AutoFixture, however, is a community project, and other people found it useful enough to implement it.

I don't think there's any reason that *by design* `AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization` doesn't set up generic methods; I think the simple reason is that *it's hard to do*. In other words, it's not that AutoFixture *will not* do that for you, but rather that it *can't*.

---

All that said, in the spirit of [GOOS](http://bit.ly/growingoos), I think you should *listen to your tests*. If the tests are difficult to write, it usually means that the [SUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_under_test) is difficult to use. That ought to first trigger reflection about the SUT, not the tests.

Could you design the SUT so that you don't *need* this AutoFixture feature?